# Error when running distance matrix in QGIS 3.4.10

Tags: qgis, error, distance-matrix

I just recieved this error when running the distance matrix in QGIS 3.4.10. I have been using this with success but am now receiving this error. I have checked the data and I cannot see anything different that would cause an error.

I was running the Standard (N x T) distance matrix.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 145, in processAlgorithm
nPoints, feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointDistance.py", line 270, in regularMatrix
fields, source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())
Exception: unknown`

Comment: Check if your point layer is not a _multipoint_ geometry type as this could cause issues. If it is, try saving it as a normal point type or run the `Multipart to singleparts` tool.

Comment: One of the lines of the error message mentions CRS, so check if there's something different about the point layer's CRS.

Comment: I have checked and both are singlepart and the CRS are both 27700

Comment: @csk could it be a limit on the number of points?

Comment: That's possible. You can test that idea by trying it with a subset of your data. Other than that, I'm not sure what else it could be. You can check the issue tracker to see if any similar issues have been reported, and make a bug report if not. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Thanks @csk. I have submitted a bug report and can confirm that it works fine on QGIS 2.18. I have not yet tested the subset